# How to create an infowindow on a multiple markers google map?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, infowindow

I'm trying to implement infowindow popping up on my multiple custom markers that I add with AJAX onto Google Maps, but I doesn't seem to be working. Before I started experimenting with  infowindow and added listenMarker() function everything worked perfectly, I had multiple icons on my map in all right locations. But I need infowindow as well when clicking on them. Here is my code:

Here I call all I need by clicking:

```
var latitd;
var longtd;

$(document).ready(function() {  
      $('#earthquakes').click(function() {
        $("#sideinfo ul").empty(function(){
          createMarker(); 
           listenMarker();
        }); 
     getQuakes();
     initMap();
    });  
  });
```

And here are my functions and google map initialization + infowindow listener.

```
function getQuakes() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=" + yesterDate + '&endtime=' + displayDate,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.features, function(key, val) {
                titleName = val.properties.place;
                var coord = val.geometry.coordinates;
                locationD = {
                    latd: coord[1],
                    lngd: coord[0]
                };

                latitd = locationD.latd;
                longtd = locationD.lngd;
  displayMarkers(); 
            });
        }
    });
}


function displayMarkers() {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitd, longtd);
    var name = titleName;
    createMarker(latlng, name);
}

function createMarker(latlng, name) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        title: name,

    });
}

function initMap() {
    var firstLat = 10;
    var firstLng = 10;    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: parseInt(firstLat),
            lng: parseInt(firstLng)
        },
        zoom: firstZ,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });


    function listenMarker(marker) {
        // so marker is associated with the closure created for the listenMarker function call
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            tooltip.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `tooltip.open(map, marker);` to open an info window. In your `listenMarker` function, use **`infowindow.open(map, marker);`**

### Initialize the info window itself:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
```

[Full example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)